# How do I horizontally center a widget using grid in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a label that aligns itself to the center of the screen. How do I go about it using grid()? This is the code I currently have. I want to center the "Menu" label.

```
import tkinter as tk
w = tk.Tk()
head = tk.Label(text = "Menu",font = ("Garamond",40))
head.grid(column = 0,row = 0,)
w.geometry("600x600")
app = tk.Button(text="Entrees",width = 13,height = 2)
main = tk.Button(text="Mains",width = 13,height = 2)
des = tk.Button(text="Dessert",width = 13,height = 2)
deal = tk.Button(text="Deals",width = 13,height = 2)

app.grid(column = 0, row = 1)
main.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
des.grid(column = 2, row = 1)
deal.grid(column = 3, row = 1)

w.mainloop()
```

I messed around with rowconfigure, columnfigure and sticky but couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: In the call to `head.grid()`, include a `columnspan=4` parameter.  Currently the Label is restricted to column 0, the leftmost of the four columns, so having it centered in the window isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, widgets will be centered in the space allocated to them. Since your UI uses four columns, your label needs to span those four columns.

```
head.grid(column = 0,row = 0, columnspan=4)
```

The label still might not be centered, since you haven't instructed `grid` on what to do with any extra space that is not required by the widgets. It's not clear what you want to have happen in that case, though. As a rule of thumb I recommend always giving at least one row and one column a non-zero `weight`. Otherwise, extra space will just appear to the right and below all of your widgets.

For example, you might want to give all columns equal weight so that they all extra spaces is evenly distributed.

```
w.grid_columnconfigure((0,1,2,3), weight=1)
```

Another solution could be to use put the buttons in a separate frame managed by `grid`, and then use `pack` to lay out the header and the frame with the buttons.